# Вызов метода с массивом

Tags: java, коллекции

Нужно, чтобы метод `massClass` вызывался только один раз, а потом я его результат передавал в другие методы

```
public class Four {
    public int enterd(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        return sc.nextInt();
    }
    public ArrayList<Integer> massClass(){
        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Integer r = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 100);
            array.add(r);
        }
        System.out.println(array);
        return array;
    }

    public void plus(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int a){
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            arr.set(i, arr.get(i) + a);
        }
        System.out.println(arr);
    }

    public void minus(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int a){
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            arr.set(i, arr.get(i) - a);
        }
        System.out.println(arr);
    }
}
```

Вот main, где я и вызываю его

```
public class Programm {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Four f = new Four();
        f.plus(f.massClass(), f.enterd());
        f.minus(f.massClass(), f.enterd());
    }
}
```

Вот результат

```
[79, 76, 29, 24, 83, 15, 34, 23, 83, 72]
Enter a number: 
2
[81, 78, 31, 26, 85, 17, 36, 25, 85, 74]
[90, 92, 54, 26, 63, 6, 78, 57, 51, 95]
Enter a number: 
2
[88, 90, 52, 24, 61, 4, 76, 55, 49, 93]
```

Видно что метод, который заполняет массив, вызван 2 раза, а мне нужно вызвать его один раз и потом передавать то, что получится, уже в другие методы

Comment: Создайте новую переменную List и передавайте, в чем проблема-то?
естественно он будет вызван 2 раза, вы 2 раза функцию вызываете!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте новую переменную

```
List<Integer> list = f.massClass();
```

И далее:

```
f.plus(list, f.enterd());
f.minus(list, f.enterd());
```